# javascript set style width 80%?

Tags: javascript, styles, percentage

I want to set the width of my object to 80%. The parent div width is 100%

whats wrong?

```
var howManyDivsIHave = document.querySelectorAll('#section div.divs').length;
if(howManyDivsIHave == "1"){
    var divs = document.getElementById("section").getElementsByClassName("divs");
    divs.style.width = "80%"; 
    divs.style.height = "80%";
    divs.style.margin = "10%";
}
else if (howManyDivsIHave == "2"){
    divs.style.width = "40%"; 
    divs.style.height = "40%";
    divs.style.margin-top = "30%";
    divs.style.margin-bottom = "30%";
    divs.style.margin-left = "5%";
    divs.style.margin-right = "5%"; 
}
else if (howManyDivsIHave == "3"){
    divs.style.width = "40%"; 
    divs.style.height = "40%";
    divs.style.margin = "5%";
}
```

}

Comment: Can you not do this via css?

Comment: because it will change depending on how many i divs i have

Comment: Answer updated. I'm not going to spell this out to a tee again since this is basically a new question, but you should be able to figure it out from the update with a little thought.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** You're still not accessing the individual members of the result set. You need to iterate through the results of `getElementsByClassName` as you're still trying to set style properties on the collection of results instead of the individual results. You also need to call `getElementsByClassName` just after your call to `querySelectorAll` or your `divs` var is going to fall out of scope when you get to the `else if` blocks. You should be able to figure out how to structure your loops from the original answer, so I'll leave it unedited:

---

`childNodes` is an Array. You need to iterate through the array and set your styles on each individual element. In the code you posted you're setting the styles on the array, not the individual DOM elements. Try something like

```
var divs = document.getElementById("section").childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
    divs[i].style.width = "80%"; 
    divs[i].style.height = "80%";
    divs[i].style.margin = "10%";
}
```

Note that `childNodes` will contain all the children of your DOM element with an id of "section", so if there are other children that aren't divs under the "section" DOM element that you don't want to apply this styling to, you're going to need to do further filtering.

Comment: it isnt working..? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of undefined

Comment: that would be hard because this is a very big project... But instead of using childNodes, maybe I could give the divs a class?

Comment: You can isolate and abstract the problem code into and example that illustrates the issue at hand. Folks do it all the time here. [Put a little effort into your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and you'll get higher quality answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

childNodes is a NodeList or array. You need to iterate through and add that style to the individual items:

```
for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
    divs[i].style.width = "80%";
    divs[i].style.height = "80%";
    divs[i].style.margin = "10%";
}
```